# Making multiple requests and passing them to a template (Express + Node.js + FB open graph)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I am building an Express Node.js appication using [this Facebook SDK](https://github.com/amachang/facebook-node-sdk), and here is my current route for root:

```
app.get('/', Facebook.loginRequired(), function (req, res) {

    req.facebook.api('/me', function(err, user) {

        res.render('index', {title: 'title', user: user});

    });


});
```

I am making a call to the FB open graph URL http://graph.facebook.com/me, but I'd like to make multiple open graph calls to pass to my template. For example:

```
var APIcalls = ['/me', '/me/music', '/me/music.listens'];

req.facebook.api(APIcalls, function(err, res1, res2, res3){

    res.render('index', {res1: res1, res2: res2, res3: res3});

});
```

What is the easiest way to make multiple API calls to Facebook and then pass the responses to my template accordingly? You can see [my full app.js file here](https://github.com/mager/soundfeed/blob/master/app.js). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This scenario seems perfect for async.map 
see here: https://github.com/caolan/async#map

the async.map method takes an array of items and performs the same async call for each item in your array in parallel. If no errors are encountered, it will call a callback with a new array of results.

so your example would look something like this:

```
var async = require('async'),
    APIcalls = ['/me', '/me/music', '/me/music.listens'];

async.map(APIcalls, 
  function(item, callback){
    req.facebook.api(item, function(err, user) {
      if(err){
        return callback(err); 
      };
      callback(null, user);
  });},
  function(err, results){
    if(err){
      throw new Error(err);
    }
    res.render('index', results);
  }
);
```

Comment: isn't Sean's answer, using batching better? It would mean a single request rather than several in parallel? Is there a reason you can't use batching? 
Thanks for accepting my answer anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use [batching](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/17/batch-requests-in-graph-api/) so that you can get away with only a *single* request to the Graph API.

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', {
    batch: [{
      relative_url: '/me'
    },{
      relative_url: '/me/music'
    },{
      relative_url: '/me/music.listens'
    }]
  }, function(o) {
    console.log(o);
  });
```

Alternatively you can use multi-fql

```
FB.api('/fql', {
    q1: 'select ....',
    q2: 'select ...'
  }, function(o) {
    console.log(o);
  });
```

Once that is done, you simply combine the data into a single model that you pass to the renderer.